# Execute contents of rjs after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I would like to alert something after my form has been updated

This is my code for the update method:

```
def update
  node_id = session[:node_id]
  @node = Node.find(node_id)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @node.update_attributes(params[:node])
    format.html {redirect_to add_loc_path(:node_id=>session[:node_id])} #redirects use to current page
    format.js #allowing the update method to respond to JavaScript
   end
  end
end
```

This is the code of the form:

```
<% form_for @expression, :url => { :controller => "expressions", :action => "update" } do |f| %>
...
<%= link_to_remote "say Hello", :url => { :controller => "expressions", :action => "update" }, :method => :get  %>
<%= f.submit 'Update' %> 
<% end %>
```

**update.js.rjs:**

```
page.alert('Hello')
```

If i click on the remote link 'say Hello', the content of 'update.js.rjs' is alerted. However if i click on the 'Update button', nothing is alerted, in fact i get the error:

```
    try {
    alert("Hello");
    }

 catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('alert(\"Hello\");'); throw e }
```

I don't understand why update.js.rjs seems to work fine for 'link_to_remote' but gives an error when being called after clicking on the  `<%= f.submit 'Update' %>` button

Is it possible to execute the contents of a rjs file after clicking on the Update button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `remote_form_for` instead of the normal `form_for`.